# Please help me in debugging this python code

Tags: python

This is a program that finds anagrams for words greater than 15 letters.There's no syntax error but the output is not as expected.I will be extremely grateful if u could point out the logical error in the program.
I downloaded the word list from http://thinkpython.com/code/words.txt
PS-I am new to Python.If there's a better approach please tell me....

```
def anagrams():
    fin1=open('words.txt')
    val=-1
    fin2=open('dic.txt')
    for i in range(100000):
        fin2.seek(0)              
        word1=fin1.readline()
        if len(word1)>18:               
            for j in range(100000):
                word2=fin2.readline()
                flag=1
                if len(word2)==len(word1)and word1!=word2:

                    for k in range(len(word1)-1):
                        if word1.find(word2[k])==-1:
                            flag=1
                            break
                        else:
                            flag=0
                if flag==0:
                    print word2,'is anagram of ',word1,'\n'
```

Comment: Add sample inputs and expected outputs

Comment: What output did you expect (on what input), and what did you get instead?

Comment: val=-1 and you dont use val again? so why you defined it

Comment: dic.txt contains the same word as words.txt I just made another file containing the words because i didn't know any other way.

Comment: in the description you say `words greater than 15 letters` but in the code you have `len(word1)>18`

Comment: Where did the `range(1000001)` come from?  Why not just read until the end of the file?

Comment: fin2=open('dic.txt')  -- did you provide any dic.txt file?

Comment: Also, the method you're using (`find`) wont handle if one word has the same character in more than once. eg `abash` would match `bahts`

Comment: sorry,i forgot to delete val=1,its of no use

Comment: well actually i don't know how to use eof in python(it didn't work when i tried) so instead i set the limit as 1000000 thinking it to be long enough.

Comment: Sample output is very long.Actually it will just show the anagrams of words that are greater in length than 15.for example interrelatednesses is anagram of  perpendicularities (which is wrong)

Comment: @DarkLord you can use `for line in fin1:` which will give you data from the file a line at a time

Answer (score 0):

Not related to the code you've posted, but you can do this using simple [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) objects, which will maintain the Count of all the characters for you.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def is_anagram(string1, string2):
...     return Counter(string1) == Counter(string2)
... 
>>> is_anagram("anagram anagram", "gramana anagram")
True
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that if both words have the same letters but in different amounts, you will claim they are anagrams when they are not.

Some improvements:

- To see if two words are anagrams, sort the letters in each & compare (they should be the same) (or use `Counter` as suggested elsewhere)
- Your code will test each pair of words twice: (word1,word2) and later (word2,word1).

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the improvements. Will the condition len(word2)==len(word1) not address the problem?if both words have the same letters but in different amounts then their lengths will be different so it wont even enter the loop,right?

Comment: aab & abb: Length is a necessary, but not sufficient, condition for anagram-ness (anagrammty?)